# Jasmine: how to test a Promise.then block?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I want to test a scenario where I have to call a function (from a service which is private readonly) in which there is an async call, then some variables are getting updated etc.

```
myFunction(param) {
    this.myService
        .serviceFunction(params)
        .then((resp) => {
          let someData = this.transformData(resp);
          this.anotherFunction(someData);
          if (param) {
            // something
          } else {
            // something else
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          // catching errors
        });
  }
```

In my spec.ts, I tried to mock the serviceFunction call, but it looks like it's not even going in the .then block at all.

```
spyOn(myService, 'serviceFunction').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(RESPONSE_MOCK));
expect(component.transformData).toHaveBeenCalled(); // won't work
```

Do you guys have any tutorial/info to test the .then block in this scenario?
I don't have enough knowledge to figure this out myself. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options available for testing asynchronous code in Angular. Some examples are `async/await`, `fakeAsync/tick` and `waitForAsync`. I will show you examples of `async/await/fixture.whenStable()` and `fakeAsync/tick`.

async/await

```
it('does xyz', async () => {
  spyOn(myService, 'serviceFunction').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(RESPONSE_MOCK));
  // do stuff
  //
  // Wait until all promises have resolved or rejected before continuing.
  await fixture.whenStable();

  expect(component.transformData).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

fakeAsync/tick

```
it('does xyz', fakeAsync(() => {
  spyOn(myService, 'serviceFunction').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(RESPONSE_MOCK));
  // do stuff
  //
  // Wait until all promises have resolved or rejected before continuing.
  tick();

  expect(component.transformData).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

You can research more about `async/await/fixture.whenStable()`, `waitForAsync` and `fakeAsync/tick`.

Comment: I applied the async/await one and it worked, thank you man. I now understand better the life cycle of a unit test.

Comment: Well explained.